# ANTLR4 how to add a text except "{{" and "}}"?

Tags: antlr4

I need to implement a grammar for the template language
It will be something like it

```
TEXT: ... // something except '{{' '}}'
NOT_A_TEXT: '{{' ... '}}';
```

Problem is that separated curly brackets are allowed in text So,

```
{ something inside }
```

will be a text

How to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
TEXT
 : TEXT_ATOM+
 ;

NOT_A_TEXT
 : '{{' .*? '}}'
 ;

fragment TEXT_ATOM
 : '{' ~'{' // a '{' followed by something other than '{'
 | '}' ~'}' // a '}' followed by something other than '}'
 | ~[{}]    // something other than '{' and '}'
 ;
```

But by matching `{{ ... }}` in the lexer, don't you loose to much information? Don't you need to parse whatever is inside `{{` and `}}`? When you match it as a single token, you cannot extract any information what's inside it easily.